# Uploading image to WebDav server with Python

Tags: python, image, file-upload, webdav

I am trying to upload an image to WebDAV Server. The server is hosted on a Linux server, and we can show the images in the WebDAV server using the URL. I am just trying to do a simple upload.

```
from webdav3.client import Client

options = {
    'webdav_hostname': "http://www.link.com/webdav/",
    'webdav_login': "user",
    'webdav_password': "user"
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client(options)
    client.upload_file(remote_path='blank.php/webdav/converted_images',
                       local_path="../Downloads/download.jpeg")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/webDav_test/test.py", line 30, in <module>
    local_path="../Downloads/download.jpeg")
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/webdav3/client.py", line 70, in _wrapper
    res = fn(self, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/webdav3/client.py", line 491, in     raise RemoteParentNotFound(urn.path())
webdav3.exceptions.RemoteParentNotFound: Remote parent for: /webdav/converted_images not found
```